# GridView AutoGenerateColumns and sorting

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, sorting

Question about GridView sorting in VB.NET:

I have a GridView with `AutoGenerateColumns = True`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" FooterStyle-BackColor="Aquamarine"
  AutoGenerateColumns="true" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="Gridview1_Sorting"
  AllowPaging="True" PageSize="12" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated"
  RowStyle-Wrap="true" runat="server" Width="100%" >
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#E0E0E0" ForeColor="#000000"/>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="Aquamarine" />
        <emptydatarowstyle backcolor="#CBE0FD" forecolor="#0000FF"/>
</asp:GridView>
```

I've declared the sort event handler (`OnSorting="Gridview1_Sorting"`), and it works fine.

However, then I change the column title (headers as they are in the DataSet which I get from the database)

```
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(0).Text = "Document" ' "PROC_UID"
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(1).Text = "Process Step" ' "PROC_DOC_UID"
```

When I set the HeaderRow text, I can no longer click on the title to sort (it also is no longer underlined).
How do I correct that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://forums.asp.net/p/996470/1691883.aspx#1691883

You'll need to find the Link Button within the control set and then update the link text.

Comment: Most excellent. Need to replace " " with &nbsp; etc. HTMLencode the link button text

            Dim tblThisCell As TableCell
            For Each tblThisCell In e.Row.Cells
                Try
                    Dim lnkButton As LinkButton = tblThisCell.Controls(0)
                    Select Case lnkButton.Text
                        Case "DOC_Bezeichnung"
                            lnkButton.Text = "Dokument"
                    End Select
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MyDebug.MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try
            Next
        End If

Answer (score 2):

You can change the column header by aliasing your columns in the sql query used by the grid:

```
Select ColumnA as [Whatever], ColumnB as [Name It This] From Table ....
```

Comment: Also good, but gives me problems because with this method I have to change my query.